# Companies using SO as a technical forum

Tags: discussion, questions

I was just about to suggest closing [How to set a form readonly (how to avoid the stay - leave popup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283191/how-to-set-a-form-readonly-how-to-avoid-the-stay-leave-popup), explaining it doesn't it look like a programming issue, and that OP should consult the people at Orbeon. I never heard of it, so I googled to read up, and also find the technical/community page: http://www.orbeon.com/community.

Lo-and-behold, for technical issues they suggest tweeting them, which is fine, but if the question gets "technical and requires a fair amount of explanations" they send them to SO.

This baffled me (never saw something like that), and thought maybe I'm misreading the question. So two question:

1. Is the question relevant to SO, or should be closed?
2. Is what these folks did OK? I can see non-programming related (more how to work their product) questions hitting SO like that?

Comment: They seem to have done the right thing. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: Thanks for the two references. I'm looking at "Make sure their question is on topic" - it seems like this would fail for any non-programming product, unless you're developing. So directing end-users here seems 'dangerous', as in an opening for an unwanted user base.

Comment: It looks like they are *configuring* software. It could be on-topic. I'm not sure if it really is an issue.

Comment: @rene and the specific question I referred to?

Comment: I can't judge that but I pinged one of the employees of Orbeon so I leave it to them to sort this out. Overall I think the questions are fine, even the one you picked.

Comment: @kabanus I think you're raising a legitimate point here, especially with the question you're pointing to. Orbeon Forms is essentially a server-side implementation of [W3C XForms](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_2.0). Writing XForms is programming. However the product also provides a UI (Form Builder) for you to create the forms. You can still edit/view the XForms, but when using Form Builder you're clearly steering away from programming, as most people understand it. However, to solve most of the problems asked about here actually requires programming.

Comment: @kabanus Tricky. I'll think more about this, and again, thank you for bringing this up. (Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers working on Orbeon Forms.)

Comment: @avernet Your response at least makes it clear to me that Orbeon is properly using SO, regardless of the quality of the specific question. Perhaps you do need a simple forum for UI questions? This will serve you as per the duplicate link - users may hit a bad experience depending on who sees their question first, without even knowing why.